# ionic iOS HTTP requests fail when using `livereload`

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic noob here.

Quite simply, HTTP requests within my app work fine on an iOS simulator when:

- starting directly from within Xcode
- starting from the command line without `livereload`; for example: `ionic cordova run ios --emulator --target "iPhone-SE"`

However, when using `livereload` my "error" callback is invoked on all HTTP requests, and the parameter looks like this:

```
{
  "_body": {
    "isTrusted": true
  },
  "status": 0,
  "ok": false,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {

  },
  "type": 3,
  "url": null
}
```

What gives?

Comment: How did you solved this. I am facing this issue since long